# VS code extreme CPU usage for no reason

Tags: visual-studio-code

I reinstall Nodejs on my PC and got stuck with VS code performance, it's not working at all and just taking all CPU's time. Also "intellisense" stops working.
I noticed it happens when I open an Angular project which uses AngularFire 2 package.

What is the issue?

[image: CPU Loafing]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Process Explorer to figure out where your CPU cycles are being spent:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: The issue was having two folders: _node_modules_ and node_modules under my project root folder

Answer (score 0):

The issue was having two folders: node_modules and node_modules under my project root folder